# Python return type hint not satisfied in except block

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting

I have the following code snippet;

```
    def test() -> str:
        try:
            return "None"
        except ValueError:
            return None
```

Here my type checker complains about the `return None` as None is not of type `str`. This is expected. The type checker however does not complain in the following case:

```
    def test() -> str:
        try:
            raise ValueError()
            return "None"
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Can anyone explain why? Executing test in this case returns None and does not satisfy the type hint.

Comment: What _is_ your type checker? [MyPy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=b39e421c10e738364231901b907403d8) rejects the second as lacking a return statement, or as lacking a return value if I `return` instead of `pass`ing.

Comment: i used the buildin one from PyCharm

Comment: I added the MyPy Plugin to PyCharm and now my expected error is reported. The world is in order again.

Comment: "None" and None are different types. If your function expects returning String. Instead of returning None return empty string ("")

Comment: @ShishirSubedi the OP's point is that they wanted the type-checking to _tell them that_.